# Which moment is preferable to programmatically start a listener/consumer in Spring Kafka?

Tags: spring-kafka

I have similar code like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61957619/5376843). But now the question is when to start the listener programmatically, once the spring app starts. Should I write an event listener for an application event or are there more preferable ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use an `ApplicationListener` or implement `SmartLifecycle` and start the containers in the `start()` method.

Comment: what about @PostConstruct in a Listener (implements MessageListener) bean which does factory.createContainer(topic).setupMessageListener(this) ?

Comment: It is not good practice to start activity in a `@PostConstruct` method because it might be that not all beans have been constructed; this could cause problems, especially if there is some bean dependence that Spring cannot detect. Using `SmartLifecycle` ensures that all beans will have been initialized. Furthermore, manually creating a container like that means you are responsible for its lifecycle (including stopping it when the context is closed); you can do that in the `stop()` method.